# C# console application generate CSV

Tags: c#, console-application

I have a function that returns a `File`. The file is created by a String, like this:

return File(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(data.getCSV()), "text/csv", "Report.csv");

How can i generate this File to a .csv file in my folder?

Comment: what do you mean by generate?

Comment: What do you mean by "my folder"?

Comment: How can i get .csv file in my folder that's running the .exe converted from type File

Comment: what do you mean? :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your use of the `File()` method, you seem to use an `(Api)Controller` in a console application. Don't do this. Put business logic in a class library:

```
public byte[] GenerateCsv()
{
    // ...
    return System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(data.getCSV());
}
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
var csvData = BusinessLogic.GenerateCsv();
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("Report.csv", csvData);
```

And the same from your `(Api)Controller`:

```
var csvData = BusinessLogic.GenerateCsv();
return File(csvData, "text/csv", "Report.csv");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var directory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(); // assuming that the folder you are looking for is the project directory.
using(var fs = new FileStream(directory +  fileName + extension))
{
   using(var sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
   {
       //use sw to write in the appropriate way.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean

```
string path = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
```

you can get path to your folder, then you can find csv file in this folder and then overwrite it(or do something else).